# How can I get slugs from requested page in getStaticProps or getStaticPaths?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to get data for every page number.

For example:
URL: https://myapp.com/films?pagenumber=1

```
export async function getStaticProps(data) {
    console.log(data.slugs.pagenumber)//1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `getInitialProps`

```
import App from 'next/app'


class Application extends App {
 ...
}

Application.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }) => {
    return { pathname: ctx.asPath }
}

export default Application
```

now inside `Application` you have `this.props.pathname`, and it is up to you how to parse it (you can use `new URLSearchParams` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)